# Defining datetime to get year

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

Can someone help me out with this

```
    print("Created On:",issue.fields.created) #Created On: 2021-07-16T11:07:54.000+0000
    datef = issue.fields.created.strip()
    dataspl,lixo = datef.split("T")
    datetimeobject = datetime.strptime(dataspl, '%Y-%m-%d')
    datetime_object = datetime.strftime(datetimeobject, '%d/%m/%Y')
    print(datetime_object) #16/07/2021

    if datetime_object.year == something
    AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'year'
```

Why is this appening? isnt the datetime_object weel define?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be getting the `year` attribute from the `datetime` object, not from the string representation. Try `datetimeobject.year`.

PS, avoid having both `datetimeobject` variable (a datetime object) and `datetime_object` variable. These names are too similiar, especially when `datetime_object` is lying about its type (it's a string, not a `datetime` object. Even you got confused).

Answer (score 0):

`datetime.strftime(datetimeobject, '%d/%m/%Y')` [returns a *string*](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime), not a `datetime` object, so the `datetime_object` in `datetime_object = datetime.strftime(datetimeobject, '%d/%m/%Y')` is a string that "has no attribute 'year'"